# How can I access to an attribute of PEPROCESS structure?

Tags: windows, device-driver, windows-kernel

I have not any experience at all in driver development. I want to access to an attribute of the structure PEPROCESS. I have a pointer pointing to the process object, obtained via PsGetCurrentProcess routine. I have seeing already some web describing the structure internals (attributes) declaration, so I could use the offset of these attributes to get them, something like:

```
hprocess = PsGetCurrentProcess();
List = (LIST_ENTRY*)((ULONG)hproces + 0x88); //Active Process Link Offset
```

However this way leave me in the middle of a problem. I would like to make a build of this code that could be able to run in other kind of platforms (ex: x86, x86_64) and others version of Windows (XP, 7, ...); and I suppose that is not possible with that way because the offset would not be the same.

Question: Is there a not lame solution for this? Ex: something like

```
List = process->ActiveProcessLink
```

or something.

Comment: It would be preferable to declare a struct rather than explicitly using an offset.  That will also take care of the cross-platform differences provided you use the correct types.  There's no help for the fact that the contents of an undocumented structure may change depending on the version of Windows.  (Obviously, you shouldn't do this if you have any other option.)

Comment: Thanks very mouch Harry. Seems I have a serious problem here.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Declaring a struct may help, but is no guarantee of success. Other platforms may add or remove members.

Comment: Make sure you make it clear to your client/customers that you are doing this. Also, let the Microsoft application compatibility team know that they should not worry about your program.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: Excellent point; I was assuming that the third-party documentation the OP found covered all the platforms of interest, and would document such differences.  Such an assumption should of course be questioned.  If it fails, adding and removing members isn't the only problem - some of the members may have the wrong type, e.g., if only a 32-bit system was examined, a member might be shown as LONG when it is really LONG_PTR.

Comment: There aren't any "not lame" solutions to this. Perhaps you should tell us what you are actually trying to accomplish and maybe there is a better way. You CAN do things the way you're going about it, but it's very brittle as you've already noted. You have to try to put a ton of error handling around everything to try to test that the EPROCESS structure still looks like you thought it did when you wrote the code. Kernel devs have done this for years to try to pull the process name out of the EPROCESS structure. So it can be done, but it's usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use macro:
PCHAR CONTAINING_RECORD(
    [in]  PCHAR Address,
    [in]  TYPE Type,
    [in]  PCHAR Field);